# axios then in vue push objects to array

Tags: vue.js, axios, push

Why when I insert objects into an array, they are inserted and overwritten in the first method

but in the second nothing happens?

```js
    el:"#usersList",
        data () {
            return {
            users: []
            }
        },
```

**This works**

```
.then(response => (this.users = response.data))
```

**Why this does not work?**

```js
    .then(
                function (response) {
                var arr = response.data;
                const rename = null;
                arr.forEach( function(data) {
                    switch(data["prava"]) {
                        case "1":
                          data["prava"] = "User 0";
                          break;
                        case "2":
                            data["prava"] = "User 1";
                          break;
                        case "3":
                            data["prava"] = "Mod";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            data["prava"] = "Admin";
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            data["prava"] = "Owner";
                            break;
                        default:
                            data["prava"] = "User 1";
                      }
                  });
                this.users = arr;
            })
```

Comment: Check this out please. Learn how "this" keyword works in arrow function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the component instance `this` is not available inside `then` callback but if you use the arrow function it can be available :

```
.then((response)=>{
            var arr = response.data;
            const rename = null
            ...
           this.users = arr;
})
```